# Mounting a shared drive on Opensolaris

Tags: windows, mount, opensolaris

I have a shared drive on my windows XP machine i want to mount this shared drive to my open solaris machine. Example I have a shared drive which is shared to all on D:\shared This shared folder i want to mount in opensolaris.

What command should i run.Both the machine are in my network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a windows share handy right now.  Did you try opening the file browser in the GUI desktop, and going to a location like "smb://HOSTNAME/"

If it works right you should see a list of shares on that host.